# Set R home for radian -- Using R with vscode

Tags: r

I had radian working properly with an older version of R. Now I updated to the newest version and uninstalled the older one, radian can no longer find R.

I tried to set the correct path by using `radian --r-binary=/path/to/R` in the Powershell prompt. Despite finding and displaying the correct R installation in the prompt, once I quit and type `radian` again it gives me the same error "Cannot determine R HOME".

What should I type to confirme the use of "/path/to/R" as the R HOME?

Comment: `Sys.getenv("R_HOME")` to see where R think it lives.(Might be a symlink.) If you are asking how to do that from within `radian` then you may need to ask with different tags.

Answer (score 0):

Copying from the radian FAQ

> The environment variable R_BINARY could also be used to specify the path to R.
> The environment variable R_HOME could also be used to specify R home directory. Note that it is should be set as the result of R.home(), not the directory where R is located. For example, in Unix

```
$ env R_HOME=/usr/local/lib/R radian
```